# Execute multiple unix commands from SAS

Tags: unix, macros, sas

I am trying to delete a file from a SAS program. The Unix commands I want to run are:

unalias rm;

rm -f &file..txt;

How do I do this? I tried using the 'x' statement, but can't get it to work. I need the commands to run in the same shell for unalias to work AND I need the macro variable to resolve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use semi-colon (`;`) to separate multiple commands in one command string.

```
x "unalias rm; rm -f &file..txt";
```

In general I just use a leading backslash to force Unix to NOT use the alias for command.

```
x "\rm -f &file..txt";
```

Comment: Thanks! I had tried to do something like your first suggestion, but couldn't get it to work. My situation is actually a little more complicated because I am also using a wildcard (*), which might be why I was having trouble. Using a backslash works perfectly though.